# FacebookAds SDK Cursor not working on /reportstats endpoint

Tags: php, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the [facebook-php-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk) version 2.2.4 (the newest at the time of this writing). I've noticed that the Cursor that is returned with calls to `$adAccount->getReportStats()` is broken with the implicit fetch option. The cursor is *expecting* to see in the response the following structure:

```
{
    "paging": { "cursor": { "after": "<some_url>" } }
}
```

However, the `/reportstats` endpoint returns the paging information structured like this:

```
{
    "paging": { "next": "<some_url>" }
}
```

I could have sworn it was working as expected a few days ago, so perhaps facebook's API has changed?

Here is an example:

```
$adAccount = new AdAccount('some_id');

// cursor is an instance of FacebookAds\Cursor.
$cursor = $adAccount->getReportStats($someFields, $someParams);
$cursor->setUseImplicitFetch(true);

foreach ($cursor as $item) {
   // do stuff
}
// cursor is never advanced to next paged result.
```

As you can see in this snipped from FacebookAds\Cursor, when implicit fetch is set to true, the cursor only checks for `paging.cursor.after|before`:

```
<?php

namespace FacebookAds;

use FacebookAds\Http\RequestInterface;
use FacebookAds\Http\ResponseInterface;
use FacebookAds\Object\AbstractObject;

class Cursor implements \Iterator, \Countable, \arrayaccess {

      // ...

      /**
       * @return string|null
       */
      protected function getLastRequestBefore() {
        $content = $this->getLastResponse()->getContent();

        return isset($content['paging']['cursors']['before'])
          ? $content['paging']['cursors']['before']
          : null;
      }

      /**
       * @return string|null
       */
      protected function getLastRequestAfter() {
        $content = $this->getLastResponse()->getContent();

        return isset($content['paging']['cursors']['after'])
          ? $content['paging']['cursors']['after']
          : null;
      }

      // ...
}
```

The actual curl request facebook's sdk generates:

```
curl -G \
  -d "data_columns=["time_start","time_stop","spend","impressions","clicks","unique_clicks","social_clicks","unique_social_clicks","cpm","unique_ctr","reach","frequency","cost_per_unique_click","cost_per_action_type","cost_per_total_action","cpp","cpc","ctr","account_id","account_name","campaign_group_id","campaign_group_name","campaign_id","campaign_name"]" \
  -d "date_preset=last_90_days" \
  -d "time_increment=1" \
  -d "access_token=<nice_try_dude>" \
  -d "appsecret_proof=<not_getting_this_either>" \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_<account_id>/reportstats
```

And here is the response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "campaign_id": "<campaign_id>",
      "date_start": "2014-12-18",
      "date_stop": "2014-12-18",
      "time_start": 1418878800,
      "time_stop": 1418965200,
      "spend": 39.39,
      "impressions": 5127,
      "clicks": 65,
      "unique_clicks": 55,
      "social_clicks": 31,
      "unique_social_clicks": 27,
      "cpm": 7.6828554710357,
      "unique_ctr": 1.0880316518299,
      "reach": 5055,
      "frequency": 1.0142433234421,
      "cost_per_unique_click": 0.71618181818182,
      "cost_per_action_type": 0.67913793103448,
      "cost_per_total_action": 0.67913793103448,
      "cpp": 7.7922848664688,
      "cpc": 0.606,
      "ctr": 1.2677979325141,
      "account_id": "<account_id>",
      "account_name": "<account_name>",
      "campaign_group_id": "<campaign_group_id>",
      "campaign_group_name": "<campaign_group_name>",
      "campaign_name": "<campaign_name>"
    },
    {
      "..." : "x49"
    }
  ],
  "limit": 50,
  "offset": 0,
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_<account_id>/reportstats?data_columns=%5B%22time_start%22%2C%22time_stop%22%2C%22spend%22%2C%22impressions%22%2C%22clicks%22%2C%22unique_clicks%22%2C%22social_clicks%22%2C%22unique_social_clicks%22%2C%22cpm%22%2C%22unique_ctr%22%2C%22reach%22%2C%22frequency%22%2C%22cost_per_unique_click%22%2C%22cost_per_action_type%22%2C%22cost_per_total_action%22%2C%22cpp%22%2C%22cpc%22%2C%22ctr%22%2C%22account_id%22%2C%22account_name%22%2C%22campaign_group_id%22%2C%22campaign_group_name%22%2C%22campaign_id%22%2C%22campaign_name%22%5D&date_preset=last_90_days&time_increment=1&access_token=<access_token>&appsecret_proof=<appsecret_proof>&offset=50"
  }
}
```

In the meantime, I've resorted to using the following "wrapper". Better alternatives?

```
<?php namespace PayPerClick\Market\Facebook\Data;

use FacebookAds\Cursor;

/**
 * Class MyReportCursor
 *
 * @package PayPerClick\Market\Facebook\Data
 */
class MyReportCursor implements \Iterator, \Countable, \ArrayAccess {

    /**
     * @type int
     */
    protected $position = 0;

    /**
     * @type Cursor[]
     */
    protected $cursors = [];

    /**
     * @param Cursor $cursor
     */
    public function __construct(Cursor $cursor) {
        $cursor->setUseImplicitFetch(false);
        $this->cursors[] = $cursor;
    }

    /**
     * @return Cursor
     */
    public function getCursor() {
        return $this->cursors[ $this->position ];
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->getCursor()->current()->getData();
    }

    public function next() {
        $this->getCursor()->next();
        if ($this->getCursor()->key() === null) {
            $this->advanceCursors();
        }
    }

    protected function advanceCursors() {
        if ($this->hasCursor($this->position+1)) {
            $this->getCursor()->rewind();
            $this->position++;
        } else if ($this->hasNextPage()) {
            $this->fetchNext();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function hasNextPage() {
        return $this->getNextPage() !== null;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getNextPage() {
        $content = $this->getCursor()->getLastResponse()->getContent();

        return isset($content['paging']['next']) ? $content['paging']['next'] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function hasCursor($offset) {
        return isset($this->cursors[ $offset ]);
    }

    protected function fetchNext() {
        parse_str(parse_url($this->getNextPage(), PHP_URL_QUERY), $previousParams);

        $objectPrototype = clone $this->getCursor()->offsetGet($this->getCursor()->getIndexRight());
        $request         = $this->getCursor()->getLastResponse()->getRequest()->createClone();

        $request->getQueryParams()->offsetSet('offset', $previousParams['offset']);

        $this->getCursor()->rewind();

        $this->position++;

        $this->cursors[ $this->position ] = new Cursor($request->execute(), $objectPrototype);
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->getCursor()->key();
    }

    public function valid() {
        return $this->getCursor()->valid();
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return $this->getCursor()->offsetExists($offset);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->getCursor()->offsetGet($offset);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->getCursor()->offsetSet($offset, $value);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        $this->getCursor()->offsetUnset($offset);
    }

    public function count() {
        return array_reduce($this->cursors, function ($a, $cursor) {
            return $a + $cursor->count();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a bug to their github.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the response when it is a "Time-based Pagination"  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

Comment: The problem is that the /reportstats endpoint does not return those cursor parameters. What confuses me, is that the SDK assumes it does.

Comment: reportstats is a time based api as explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2#params, and here:   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/chapter-7-ad-report-stats

Comment: I realize that the API is time based. However, Facebooks sdk returns the same cursor iterator for calls to reportstats as it does for the other end points. Obviously this causes problems.

Comment: Am I missing something? I'll update the example in my post to reflect the parameters I'm sending. Let's say that the result has 500 rows. Even when setting the cursor::useImplicitFetch(true), the cursor only iterates through 50 rows (the default limit in the api). I AM passing in either time_interval or date_range parameters.

Comment: So dump the response and post it here.

Comment: I posted an example of the response from the api. As you can see, the paging returned does not have the cursor settings but Cursor.php won't use implicit search with out those. The sdk returns the same Cursor object for ALL api calls, that's the problem.

Comment: No it does not return thr cursors for all calls. Raed the documentation. I have linked to the relevent pages of it. Time based calls only return the previous and next. This question has been answered so please close it.

Comment: Um, the question has not been answered. Are you mistaking the term "SDK" with "API"? `AdAccount::getReportStats()` calls `AdAccount::getManyByConnection()` which returns `new Cursor()`. As I had stated, that cursor **PHP** class in the **official SDK** (found in the link in my question) needs the response to contain the [cursor][before|after] to have implicit fetching enabled. I understand that the **API** only returns previous and next, but the Cursor class can't use those to use implicit fetching...

Comment: Yes, and I followed that link and the subsequent link from there to Cursors which is where it states that time-based etc. So, there is a miss-match between the 2. Now I don't see how the SDK can magically fetch a cursor from an API that does not return one otherwise: the API must return one for the SDK to use one. Why not take this to the Facebook forum, I'm sure they have one for this.

Comment: The MyCursor class I posted is an example of a wrapper that allows for the same implicit fetch behavior. I'm interested in how others have tackled this bug.

Comment: Well, you could issue a pull request on that sdk github project and fix the cursor class directly with your patch. Be nice for other people who encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly probably bug in [facebook-php-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/tree/master/src/FacebookAds/Object). Even [Facebook API examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2#overview) show it as:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

$account = new AdAccount('act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');

$params = array(
    'date_preset'=>'last_28_days',
    'data_columns'=>"['adgroup_id','actions','spend']",
);

$stats = $account->getReportsStats(null, $params);

foreach($stats as $stat) {
    echo $stat->impressions;
    echo $stat->actions;
}
```

Unfortunately - it is, indeed, **time-based paging** so **cursor data won't be returned** from it. It's already filled as an issue on GitHub - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/issues/76

**EDIT:** Oh, it is you who filled that bug :)